# Add CKEDITOR in dynamic text field in Laravel : Error code: editor-element-conflict

Tags: angularjs, ajax, laravel, ckeditor

I want to add ckeditor in dynamic field in laravel. The ckeditor script file is

```
<script>
  $(function() {
  $('.ckeditor').each(function(){  
CKEDITOR.replace($(this).attr('id'), {
extraPlugins: 'mathjax',
mathJaxLib: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML',
height: 100
});
});  
  });  
</script>
```

The view page is like

```
     <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="i in range(total_answers) track by $index" ng-if="total_answers > 0">
     
    <fieldset class="form-group col-md-4" >
        <label >Option @{{ $index+1 }}</label> <span class="text-red">*</span>
        <input type="textarea" name="options[]" id="option_@{{ $index }}" class="form-control ckeditor" placeholder="Option @{{ $index+1 }}" ng-model="answers[$index].option_value">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-group col-md-4" >
        <label >Option @{{ $index+1 }} (2nd Language) </label> 
        <input type="text" name="optionsl2[]" id="optionl2_@{{ $index }}" class="form-control ckeditor" placeholder="Option 2nd lang @{{ $index+1 }}" ng-model="answers[$index].optionl2_value">
        
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Please help me, i don't know where is the issue

Comment: What the error you get?

Comment: i am getting this error. [CKEDITOR] Error code: editor-element-conflict.

Answer (score 0):

None of your elements have a class of "ckeditor", which is what your script is looking for. Add that class to a textarea and it should work for you as long as you don't have any other issues.

Comment: I added ckeditor class actually but didn't get any editor in text fields.

Comment: Check the console log in your browser (F12) and see if there are any error messages in there. Are sure you're including the package in your HTML code?